# Binary tree with python

Tags: python-2.7, binary-tree

I don't understand where am I making a mistake, the following is the code for creating a tree but it never creates the tree. I think there is some logical mistake in the `make_tree` function.

```
    class node:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a
        self.l=None
        self.r=None


class tree:
    def __init__(self, a,maxd=5):
        self.s=node(a)
        self.maxd=maxd

    def make_tree(self, n,d=0):

        if(self.maxd<d):
            return n
        else:

            n=node(d)
            n.a=d
            self.make_tree( n.l,d+1)
            self.make_tree(n.r,d+1)

            return n

t=tree(2)
t.s=t.make_tree(t.s)
print 'children ', (t.s.r!=None), (t.s.l!=None)
```

output:

> children  False False

want a tree like this:

```
     o
   /   \
  o     o
/  \   / \
o   o  o  o
```

Comment: The left and right children of `t.s` are `None` in this case, which is why you're getting that output. What is the desired output?

Comment: yes they are None, but I am creating new node in make-tree function, so after calling make_tree function tree should be created.

Comment: is my function wrong for creating a tree?

Comment: You're calling `make_tree` on the created node several times. Each time that node is created, its left and right are set to `None`, according your `Node`'s `__init__`. It might help to have a diagram of what you want the tree to look like

Comment: when I recursively call make_tree function with left node and right node as input it creates new node in else part for them. so shouldn't it work? and make a tree. like normal binary tree of given depth

Comment: You're calling `self.make_tree`, not `self.left.make_tree`. That might be the missing piece

Comment: it helped, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're expecting the line:

```
n=node(d)
```

to do more than it can do in Python. That line rebinds the local name `n`, but it doesn't change where the original `n` value came from in the calling code.

I think you should skip passing `n` to the `make_tree` function entirely and simply use its return value instead:

```
def make_tree(self, d=0):
    if d > self.maxd:
        return None
    n = Node(d)
    n.l = self.make_tree(d+1)
    n.r = self.make_tree(d+1)
    return n
```

You'd call it with something like:

```
tree.s = tree.make_tree()
```

Of course, `make_tree` could be a regular function rather than a method, since it only uses `self` to call itself recursively.